# Sending group name as claims in ADFS 3.0

Tags: active-directory, ldap, claims, adfs3.0

I need to add a claim rule for a RP in ADFS 3.0 to issue all the group names to which the user is added as claims if the group names are, say A, B, C. How can I achieve this? As of now, I'm using LDAP attribute Token-Groups - Unqualified Names which will provide all group names which he is part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the groups with regex.

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://claims/MyGroups"), query = ";tokenGroups;{0}", param = c.Value);

then something like:

c:[Type == "http://claims/MyGroups", Value =~ "^(?i)A"]
 => issue(claim = c);

and so on.